# carouFredSel: fade effect during scroll: only at the scrolled elements

Tags: caroufredsel

I see nine elements: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]

The scrolled element(s) (one at click and three at mouseweel) have a "hard edge" during the scroll-out or scroll-in at the white wrapper div-container.

at click to right: <0 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

at mousewheel down: <0 1 2 [3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11]

So I testet the scroll option "Scroll using a custom effect and easing-animation during 1 second." http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/code-examples/configuration.php with

```
...
view: 9,
scroll : {
items: 1,
fx : "crossfade",
easing : "linear",
duration : 1500
}
...
```

BUT

the crossfade-effekt works at all nine elements and not at the two (or six) elements that scroll out and scroll in.

Have you a solution for fade-out the item 0 and fade-in item 10 at click or fade-out item 0,1, 2 and fade-in item 9, 10, 11 at mousewheel?

Thanks